# Access query calculation Vs. Excel calculation where access query is data source

Tags: performance, excel, ms-access

Setup is an Access back-end on a network drive with a query as data source for an Excel table. I want to know if it is better to perform complex calculations in Excel after the data has been imported vs having the calculation in the query itself.

For example:

The db collects quality control information with individual records for every component of a lot. One calculation checks that all components of each lot have been recorded and if so checks that the most recent component has been entered before the scheduled completion time.

Obviously this is a fairly intensive calculation in excel which leads to significant calculation time after the data has been imported. (It's very possible that the calculation isn't as efficient as it could be!!)

So what I'd like to know is if the access query would be more or less efficient at doing this calculation (bearing in mind that the file is on a network drive).

I hope all that makes sense but if not let me know and I will try to clarify!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a general rule for which platform will be faster. It depends on the size of the task and the method chosen to implement it.

MSAccess is absolutely great at collating information, but that is because it is flexible and systematic, which helps prevent errors. Not because collating information is fast. There is no general rule that says collating information will be faster in MSAccess, Excel, SQL Server or C#.

If you are using a code loop to compare all cells, that can take a long time however you do it. Post the code here to see if there is a suggestion on how to convert it to calculated cell expressions. To make Excel fast, you need to use calculated cell expressions.

If you aren't using a code loop, are you sure you aren't actually waiting for the database access?

Comment: Thanks for the response David. I thought that might be the case but I figured it was worth asking! The calculations are cell expressions and not vba but to be honest the problem really lies with the users prehistoric PCs. The calculation time is not hugely significant on my own PC but can take up to 3-4 minutes for some users so I wanted to see if there was some way I could improve the experience for them.